# Custom Input Keyboard for Tablet

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I am building a tablet and I really don't want to use the standard keyboard input. I am always in landscape mode so I don't think I have enough space for the way this keyboard works.  Is there any good tutorials on creating ones own custom IME?  Is the resize an option for landscape mode?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html found this one but where do you download the source?  I mean a simple way to download this as a .zip or checkout as svn? Does anyone know of any other samples?

Comment: well guys, am I the only one who does not want to see their whole screen covered with the standard keyboard when entering values?